# Simple example of using FFmpeg with php

Tags: php

How do I start using FFmpeg with php? I don't understand how to include it in my php code. Probably something super simple

And then I like to strip the audio track out of a video. All done in php

Comment: One idea is simple: just _run_ ffmepg on your server. After all, it's an executable. Another idea would be to do some research at first, there seem to be some libraries around can help you with the `php`integration. Please try to elaborate your question a little more, currently it's a little broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: Ok, so it's not like jquery where you link it in to your page? You need to install it on the server, like a softwhere?

Comment: As far as I know, `ffmepg` is an executable and you have to install and run it on your server - if you're allowed to. There are many tutorials around the web, so take a look..